# How to validate a PayPal webhook signature for Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, paypal

After a PayPal order is complete, it sends a webhook to a google script URL. Before information is sent, it has to validate the signature. Down below is a link to a Java example.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/notification-messages/#

How to validate a PayPal webhook signature for Google Script?

I've looked through the google-apps-script and PayPal tags for a solution, but it only provides IPN solutions. From my understanding that's an older method. Perhaps that's the only way. I don't know. I'm new to API handling, so I may be wording the problem incorrectly.

EDIT: Did some more digging and was able to receive and process a paypal webhook.

```
function doPost(e) {
    var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
    params = JSON.parse(params);
    var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

The next problem is setting up the PayPal Smart button to send the correct webhook. The correct webhook event would be "Checkout order completed" (tested via PayPal's Webhooks simulator). This webhook contains the order information. The examples over at [PayPal Smart Button Demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout-v4/#/pattern/buynow) calls onAuthorize as a webhook. This webhook does not contain the information I want. I'll make a separate post about this.

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            window.alert('Payment Complete!');
        });
    }
```

So I guess no validation is required for webhooks, maybe.

Comment: Can you receive details:  `return actions.payment.execute().then(function(details)`

Comment: When that is ran, a "Payment sale completed" and "Payments payment created" webhooks get sent. Within "Payments payment created" the buyer/customer details are listed. Does that event type mean that everything went through? I imagine no. So I would store the PAYID of 'Payments payment created" along with the info I need. Once "Payment sale completed" is received, I look for the matching PAYID value and set that customer to paid. Storing the values within a spread sheet.

Comment: It seems that you are using a Google Sheet as a customer database for recording  the payment status and order details.  As long as the client side code confirms that the payment was executed, then you could display a message to the customer that the order was successful.  Of course the information that you get in your `doPost()` function will confirm what happened.  If you are shipping a product, then you'd rely on the POST to your Sheet.  If you're giving immediate access to the customer for an app or add-on or a download, that's a little different.

Comment: Yes, I record the customer's email and send them files. The sending files by email part, I got figured out. The getting the customers info from PayPal, I'm pulling my hair out. Trying to get the email info from the JSON, but having trouble doing so.

Comment: Can't "params.resource.transactions.payee.email" be used to get the email?

Comment: Stringify `e` -  `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))`  View your logs in: [https://script.google.com/home/executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions)  Whatever is in `e` is available to you for information.  Can you post that?

Comment: After 5 hours of back and forth, I got it to work. It adds the email, name, and paypal id from the "Payments payment created" webhook and paypal id from "Payment sale completed". One last question cause the comment section is getting too long. Is there any gurantee that the "Payments payment created" webhook is recieved and processed first? Cause I want to append the "Payments payment created" details to sheet then once the recieve "Payment sale completed", looks for a matching paypal id.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and you should.  Please add an answer with what you now know, and some code.  Providing an answer will help anyone who is looking for information.  Your other question should be a new post.  But if it's too general, it won't be considered a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I got a semi-working system.

```
function doPost(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Debug').getRange('A1').setValue("Recieved doPostCommand");

    var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

    try {
        if (myData.event_type == 'PAYMENTS.PAYMENT.CREATED') {
            var email = myData.resource.payer.payer_info.email
            var name = myData.resource.payer.payer_info.first_name + " " + myData.resource.payer.payer_info.last_name
            var payID = myData.resource.id
  
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Debug').getRange('A3').setValue(email);
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Debug').getRange('A4').setValue(name);
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Debug').getRange('A5').setValue(payID);
        } else if (myData.event_type == 'PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED'){
            var payID = myData.resource.parent_payment

            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Debug').getRange('A7').setValue(payID);
        } 
    } catch (e) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Debug').getRange('E1').setValue("Error: " + e);
    }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

I found the webhooks to work some of the time. Sometimes they failed while other times they are received. When they are received, the webhooks don't necessarily arrive in a specific order.

So to confirm a payment complete, append the customer details (including PayPal ID) to a "customer" sheet. To a separate "confirmed payment id" sheet, append the PayPal IDs. From there, add a listener to when a PAYMENTS.PAYMENT.CREATED or a PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED webhook is received, check if there are matching PayPal IDs. The "confirmed payment id" sheet will act as a buffer. From there set the payment completed column to true for the correct customer and delete the PayPal ID from the buffer sheet.

That's how I would do it, but webhooks seem to be trash atm. I'll have to resort to some eCommerce service. I hope someone finds this useful. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

IPN is a much older solution that is separate to webhooks.

Regarding webhook verification, you linked to a page for DIY verification, where you calculate whether the signature matches. The example is in Java, but can conceivably be adapted to any language (with some considerable work)

The alternative way to verify a webhook is via the webhooks API, posting the message back using this API call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature

Avoid using the PayPal-*-SDKs, since that documentation was written before those SDKs were deprecated